# Datos de fecha dinámico SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Quiero realizar una forma dinamica pra poder extraer las fechas de cierre de mes desde 2019 hasta la fecha, y en base vaya pasando el tiempo vaya actualizando, por ejemplo

actualmente estamos en Mayo, entonces quiero un resultado que me traiga la siguiente información

```
Numero Mes  Mes         Year   Final Day
4          Abril        2023       30
3          Marzo        2023       31
2          Febrero      2023       28
1          Enero        2023       31
12         Diciembre    2022       31
```

este es el scrpt que estoy utilizando

```
;WITH mnths AS (
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) Mes, YEAR(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) Years, DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) FinalDay, 12 Orden
UNION 
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) Mes, YEAR(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) Years, DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) FinalDay, 11 Orden
UNION 
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-3)) Mes, YEAR(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-3)) Years, DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-3)) FinalDay, 10 Orden
UNION 
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-4)) Mes, YEAR(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-4)) Years, DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-4)) FinalDay, 9 Orden
UNION 
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-5)) Mes, YEAR(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-5)) Years, DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-5)) FinalDay, 8 Orden
)

SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Enero' THEN '1'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Febrero' THEN '2'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Marzo' THEN '3'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Abril' THEN '4'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Mayo' THEN '5'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Junio' THEN '6'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Julio' THEN '7'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Agosto' THEN '8'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Septiembre' THEN '9'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Octubre' THEN '10'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Noviembre' THEN '11'
    WHEN mnths.Mes = 'Diciembre' THEN '12'
END AS [Numero Mes],
mnths.Mes, mnths.Years, mnths.FinalDay 
INTO #FiltroMes

FROM mnths 

ORDER BY mnths.Orden DESC
```

Sin embargo, quiero que llegue desde 31 enero 2019 hasta Abril (que es el ultimo mes ya que mayo no ha terminado), creo que de esta forma es realizarlo manual, ya que cuando sea Junio, me tomara desde Febrero 2019 hasta Mayo 2023, lo cual no es lo que quiero ya que deseo que siempre sea desde Enero 2019 hasta el ultimo mes que cerro

no se si con ese script actual funcionaria con un ciclo while o como podria realizarlo

Comment: ¿La _fecha de cierre_ de un més es siempre el último día del mes?

Comment: Perdón, no se entiende bien la parte donde expones el problema con el código. ¿QUieres que siempre comience en Enero de 2019? Lo importante es entonces el mes de cierre, que sería _el último mes completado previo al actual_? ¿El cierre es en el último día calendario del mes?

Comment: @jachguate correcto

Comment: @Alfabravo tal cual lo dijiste, quiero que siempre comience el enero 2019 hasta el último mes completado previo al actual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes valerte de

- Un generador de números consecutivos, por ejemplo, utilizando `row_number()` sobre alguna tabla que tenga muchos datos. Yo suelo usar tablas del diccionario de datos, que tienen un costo de uso muy bajo pues suelen estar en memoria en el servidor. Por ejemplo:

  ```
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.all_columns
  ```

  Nos devolverá un listado de números de 1 a más de 10K en una base de datos típica de manera casi instantánea.
- Aplicar este generador de números multiplicados por -1 a la función `eomonth()`, hasta llegar a la fecha inicial de tu interés. Eso garantiza ir, por ejemplo, del mes anterior hasta enero del 2019, pasando por todos los meses.
- Finalmente, utilizar las funciones [`year()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql), [`month()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql), [`day()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) y [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) para obtener los datos separados de cada una de las fechas.
- Adicionalmente, hago [`set language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) para obtener los nombres de los meses en español, aunque podrías obviar este paso si quieres los nombres de los meses en el idioma de la conexión del usuario.

Poniendo todas las piezas juntas:

```
declare @FechaInicial date = '20190101';

SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

with
num as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.all_columns
)
,
Fechas as (
select EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -n) FechaCierre
  from num
)
select   Month(FechaCierre) NumeroMes
       , DateName(Month, FechaCierre) NombreMes
       , Year(FechaCierre) Year
       , Day(FechaCierre) FinalDay
       , FechaCierre
  from Fechas
 where FechaCierre >= @FechaInicial
 order by FechaCierre desc;
```

Me devuelve un resultado como este (Omito la mayoría de filas en el ejemplo con ...):

```
Se cambió la configuración de idioma a Español.
NumeroMes   NombreMes         Year        FinalDay    FechaCierre
----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
4           Abril             2023        30          2023-04-30
3           Marzo             2023        31          2023-03-31
2           Febrero           2023        28          2023-02-28
1           Enero             2023        31          2023-01-31
12          Diciembre         2022        31          2022-12-31
11          Noviembre         2022        30          2022-11-30
...
3           Marzo             2020        31          2020-03-31
2           Febrero           2020        29          2020-02-29
1           Enero             2020        31          2020-01-31
...
3           Marzo             2019        31          2019-03-31
2           Febrero           2019        28          2019-02-28
1           Enero             2019        31          2019-01-31

(52 rows affected)
```

Una vez comprendidos los pasos, se puede obtener el mismo resultado con esta consulta (un poco menos legible en mi opinión).

```
select   Month(FechaCierre) NumeroMes
       , DateName(Month, FechaCierre) NombreMes
       , Year(FechaCierre) Year
       , Day(FechaCierre) FinalDay
       , FechaCierre
  from (select eomonth(GETDATE(), -ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null))) FechaCierre 
          from sys.all_columns) mes
 where FechaCierre >= '20190101'
 order by FechaCierre desc;
```

Comment: Gran respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una variante de la respuesta de jachguate. La diferencia es que genero la secuencia de números al vuelo y eso evita tener lecturas en disco. También tiene una optimización para trabajar únicamente con las filas necesarias.

La diferencia es mínima en cuanto a rendimiento porque la otra versión es bastante rápida gracias a la poca cantidad de filas. Pero la diferencia es que una dura un poco más de 30ms y la otra aparece como 0. La diferencia en tiempos es gracias al TOP al momento de generar las filas.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteMeses(mes) AS(
    --Generamos solo las filas necesarias calculando la diferencia en meses desde Enero 2019 a la fecha
    SELECT TOP( DATEDIFF(MM, '20190101', GETDATE())) 
        --Le sumamos los meses al final del mes anterior del inicial
        DATEADD( MM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '20181231') mes
    FROM E4
)
SELECT  MONTH(mes)          AS Mes,
        DATENAME(MM, mes)   AS NombreMes,
        YEAR(mes)           AS Año,
        DAY(mes)            AS Dia,
        mes                 AS FechaCierre
FROM cteMeses;
```

Comment: +1 Creo que estoy exagerando con usar `sys.all_columns`, 10K meses daría como para 833 años de funcionamiento. Se podría seleccionar otra tabla y hacer un top para mejorarlo, pues en la práctica con poco más de un ciento de filas se tiene suficiente para un buen rato. :D

Comment: Por eso el top es tan importante, para obtener únicamente las filas que necesitamos. En este caso puede ser irrelevante, pero en funciones o vistas que se unan con tablas con millones de filas puede hacer la diferencia.

Answer (score -1):

Una variante a la solución utilizando una tabla temporal para acumular las filas de datos (la cantidad de filas se obtiene con un difference entre la fecha dada y la fecha actual) y format para localizar el nombre del mes al lenguaje necesitado.

```
   -- Creamos una tabla temporal a la que insertaremos la información pedida
    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
      Numero_Mes int,
      Mes varchar(20),
      Year varchar(5),
      Final_Day int
    )
    
    --Definimos nuestra fecha inicial
    DECLARE @date datetime2 = '2019-01-01';
    -- Contador para el loop while
    DECLARE @Contador INT 
    -- Variable para obtener la cantidades de meses
    DECLARE @MesesTotales INT 
    SET @Contador=0
    SET @MesesTotales= DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2019-01-01', GETDATE())
    
    -- Recorremos hasta el mes anterior al actual
    WHILE ( @Contador < @MesesTotales)
    BEGIN
        insert into #Temp
        SELECT
        MONTH( DATEADD(month, @Contador, @date)) AS 'Numero Mes',
        FORMAT( DATEADD(month, @Contador, @date), 'MMMM', 'es-es') AS 'Mes', --mes en idioma español
        YEAR( DATEADD(month, @Contador, @date)) AS 'Year',
        DAY(EOMONTH( DATEADD(month, @Contador, @date)) ) AS 'Final Day';
    
        SET @Contador  = @Contador  + 1
    END
    
     SELECT * FROM #Temp
    
    --Eliminamos la tabla temporal
    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP Table #Temp
    END
```

Comment: No he sido yo quién ha votado negativamente, sin embargo si argumentaría que esta solución no solo tiene más código, su desempeño va a ser menor y todavía se me hace más difícil de mantener.

Comment: Si esta forma es mucho más lenta, solo la publique como una opción para quién no pueda/quiera ocupar ROW_NUMBER